# Simplex Method - Why is my answer wrong?

Tags: operations-research, simplex-method

[image]

[image]

I know that the bottom row can't have any zeros and I didn't. Yet I still got this wrong? Is it because my RHS column has a negative?

Comment: Two questions: 1) if you pick the pivot in R2, why do you use R1 (and not the pivot) to eliminate in R3? 2) how come you get 2R2-R1? Shouldn't it be R1-2R2 $\to$ R1? The rule is strict: "a non-pivot row+(whatever)* the pivot row $\to$ the non-pivot row".

Comment: My row operations seems to be wrong, but I'm not sure why. Can you explain why you thought it was R1-2R2 -> R1? Is there certain rules I need to follow when I'm doing row operations that I perhaps forgot?

Comment: Maybe in row operations, I can't subtract. If I do that, then it all makes sense.

Comment: The rule is: the row you want to change is always on the first place. What you add to it or subtract is the pivot row. Not the other way round.

Answer (score 1):

It must be (done in MS Excel with both tables and Solver tool):

[image: ![enter image description here]

Comment: For the first tableu, why is R3 = 5R2 + R3? Didn't the 2 turn into a 1 already with your row operation R2 = R2/2? Shouldn't it be R3 = 10R2 + R3??

Comment: Yes, the results of row operations are shown in the next tables.